# Error while setting prerequisite for .net framework 3.0 in setup wizard for windows forms app c#

Tags: c#, winforms, operating-system, .net-framework-version, setup-wizard

I have created a setup file for windows forms app and .net framework is 3.0. Now i don't want it to download from internet if framework is not available on installation machine. For that i am using below option as shown in screenshot.

[Pre-requisite snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npk9o.png)

After that when i build i get following errors. How can i fix all these errors or is there any other way to achieve this?

[Error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bFEE.jpg)

Comment: You'll have to manually download all these dependencies and put them on the same location as your application, then they will be packaged with the app

Comment: Try downloading the full Service Pack [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=25150) then place it in your App's location

Comment: @Dumisani - At what location should i place this full service pack? Will it be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlClrTypes_x86. Full service pack is .exe file so i will have to install that for getting the packages right? I believe .net framework 3.5 includes both 2.0 and 3.0 just to confirm?

Comment: I think the path should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX35SP1` according to your error but I'm not too sure. I don't think you have to install it, but that should be packaged and be installed when installing your app. Yes it includes those versions too and based on your errors it's mainly 3.5 that's an issue.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with winforms since varsity but I had to perform this task before. And it was a mission